Cartesian and parametric representation of a vector subspace, given a base
I have this definition from my teacher's notes:
"Let $\phi_{\mathcal{B}}:V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$ an isomorphism such as $\phi_{\mathcal{B}} (\textbf{v})=(\textbf{v})_{\mathcal{B}}$, i.e. $\phi_{\mathcal{B}}$ associates a vector $\textbf{v} \in V$ his coordinates with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, base of $V$.
Given a proper subspace $W \subset V$, $\phi_{\mathcal{B}} (W)$ is called $\textbf{cartesian representation}$ or parametric representation of $W$ with respect to the base $\mathcal{B}$."
The exercise asks to find "a minimal parametric representation and a minimal cartesian representation" of $W$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, where:

$W=$span$((1,1,1),(2,1,1),(4,2,2)) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathcal{B}=((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1))$
$W=$span$(1,t,1+t) \subset \mathbb{R}_{\leq3}[t]$, $\mathcal{B}=(1,t,t^2,t^3)$

I've looked up the explanation for the cartesian
and parametric representations of a subspace, but I can only find explanation that suppose the standard base for $V$.
I've interpreted the concept such as an inverse method to solve linear system with Rouché-Capelli's Theorem: the subspace is the solutions' subspace and I want to find the linear system that have the exact same solutions.
I've noticed that both the bases in 1. and 2. are standard bases, how can I find the requested representations in a different base than the standard one?
In 1., I found as cartesian representation $W:y-z=0$, which is the same as the exercises solutions. As parametric representation I found  \begin{cases} x=\alpha \\ y=z= \beta \end{cases} In the notes' solutions, the parametric representation is \begin{cases} x=\alpha + 2 \beta \\y=\alpha + \beta \\ z=\alpha+\beta \end{cases}
Which one is the correct one?
To sum up:

is my interpretation correct?
what is the general method to find $\phi_{\mathcal{B}} (W)$ for any given base $\mathcal{B}$?
what is the correct answer to 1.?

P.S.: Sorry about any linguistic/grammar error, I'm not English native speaker, in case of possible doubt regarding my definitions, notations, etc..., don’t mind asking for a clarification.
